# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync always return Failure after change database connection dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net MVC code first project I have managed to change my connection string dynamically depend on login values ( the database is a copy of the main one) and correctly changed but I always get password UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword error did not match and if I neglect this code SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync always return Failure despite it is login correctly with the same main database

this is my trial ApplicationDbContext

```
  public ApplicationDbContext(string connectionstring)
        : base(connectionstring)
        {
        }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext(ConString.MeqyasdbCon(ConString.dbCatlogConn));
        }
```

login page

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, string language = Config.DefaultLanguage)
        {
 string x = model.UserName.ToLower();
            string dbName = x.Split('_').First();



            var dbname = db.dbLists.Where(t => (t.InitializationLetters == dbName)).Select(t => new { ConnString = t.ConnectionString }).ToList();
            ConString.dbCatlogConn = dbname[0].ConnString;
            //new conection
            var checkconnection = ConString.dbCatlogConn;

            using (db = new ApplicationDbContext(ConString.dbCatlogConn))
            {
                bool CheckConnResult = db.Database.Exists();

                //code here
                var user = db.Users.Where(e => e.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
                var result = new SignInStatus();
                if (user == null)
                    result = SignInStatus.Failure;
                else
                {
                    string dbPassword = dal.DecryptPassword(user.AnotherUsername, user.AnotherSalt, user.PasswordHash);
        // I had to fix dbPassword  to check where is the error
                    var status = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword("Admin", model.Password);
                    if (status == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                        // error here
                             result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, user.PasswordHash, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
                            // result = SignInStatus.Success;
                    else
                        result = SignInStatus.Failure;
                }

                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:

                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            if (user.Disabled == true)
                            {
                                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                                ModelState.AddModelError("", language == "en" ? "Invalid login attempt." : "error ");
                                // rest the connection to default
                                ConString.dbCatlogConn = ConString.MainConn;
                                return View(model);
                                //return View("Lockout");
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                user.LastLoginDateUtc = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                if (User.IsInRole(UsersTypes.Interview.ToString()))
                                {
                                    return RedirectToRoute("tutrial");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                         // returnUrl = "/"; // error it shouldn't be like this alaa mohamed
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return View("Lockout");
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", language == "en" ? "Invalid login attempt." : "error ");
                        ConString.dbCatlogConn = ConString.MainConn;
                        return View(model);
                }


            }
}
```

Comment: You pass the user.PasswordHash to the PasswordSignInAsync() method, but it should be the password of the user. The method will hash it for you. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs

Comment: but it works fine in the main database and login correctly

Comment: "SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync always return Failure despite it is login correctly with the same main database" I´m a little bit confused. Could you specific the problem a bit more?

Comment: when i login using the main databse it works perfect without any problem then when i logout and login with another login which related with another database which is a copy from the main one but with different name and different connectionstring i got two errors the first one is in UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword  and the second is in await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync

Comment: Just to get clarity, the user you are trying to log in with also exists in the new database?

Comment: the problem is that the sign manager didn't update the database new connection string it still saves the old old